# CSS - Background overwriting Bootstrap table-striped

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following class:

```
.highlight-lighter {
   background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

and the following html where I'm trying to implement a striped table using bootstrap css:

```
<div class="highlight-lighter ">
    <table class="table table-striped">
       <tbody>
          <tr class="row">
             <th class="col-sm-6">Foo</th>
             <th class="col-sm-6">Bar</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td class="col-sm-6">1</td>
             <td class="col-sm-6">2</td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="col-sm-6">3</td>
             <td class="col-sm-6">4</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I use the `highlight-lighter` class as per above the table no longer appears striped - the `highlight-lighter` class seems to override any striping of table rows?

I know I can fix by moving the `highlight-lighter` class to the last div but I want to know why it's overriding the the `table-striped` class as I would prefer to keep it as it is i.e. in the parent div?

Comment: It isn't overwriting, it's just a very similar color to the bootstrap styles. You're applying `#fafafa` and bootstrap uses `#f9f9f9` for the stripes. So applying `#fafafa` behind the table will cause the white (really just transparent) rows to appear as `#fafafa` and the striped rows are `#f9f9f9`. Do you need a solution of some sort or are you just looking to know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its not overriding the `table-striped` because this class set background color for some rows and don't set for other, it uses this selector `.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd)`

so when you use background color on the parent div then automatically that color is filled in the rows that don't have any background color

if you want to fix that you may wanna set background color to row with no background color by adding this code:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**See code snippet:**

```css
.highlight-lighter {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="highlight-lighter ">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row">
        <th class="col-sm-6">Foo</th>
        <th class="col-sm-6">Bar</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="col-sm-6">1</td>
        <td class="col-sm-6">2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="col-sm-6">3</td>
        <td class="col-sm-6">4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
```